# Integrate a multiple solution to single solution with client specific

Tags: mysql, windows, model-view-controller

I have a project in mvc which is delivered to different clients. Customization of project based on client requirement is also handled. For each client different solution is maintained and different database for each client. But now as the client size increased it became very difficult to handle different solution. Can anyone help me out a better way to handle a single solution and customization should reach as per client requirement. 
Thank you

Comment: add new tables - companydetails,company preferences- to store client details & prefreces. based on this we can assign different pref to them.. then setup a single project two many clients